# How to traverse through array within an object and return each array element as the second key value pair, along with its' corresponding ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that looks like this:

```
 {
      id: '100',
      domains: [
        'www.abc.com',
        'www.def.com'
      ]
    }
    { id: '101', domains: [ 'ghi.com' ] }
    {
      id: '102',
      domains: [ 'www.jkl.com' ]
    }
    ...
```

The final output should look like:

```
{ id: '100', url: 'abc.com' }
{ id: '100', url: 'def.com' }
{ id: '101', url: 'ghi.com' }
{ id: '102', url: 'jkl.com' }
...
```

Comment: What is the issue where you are stuck? What have you tried so far?

Comment: As is, it is difficult to guess what you are trying to accomplish. It would be helpful if you edited your question and added and actual question and more details about what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for this to map the elements to an array of results which will then be flattened together:

```js
const data = [{
    id: '100',
    domains: [
      'www.abc.com',
      'www.def.com'
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '101',
    domains: ['ghi.com']
  },
  {
    id: '102',
    domains: ['www.jkl.com']
  },
];

const result = data.flatMap(obj =>
  obj.domains.map(url => ({
    id: obj.id,
    url
  })));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize there was a flatMap() method.

Comment: It's quite new, at least much newer than e.g. `.map`. Don't forget to mark the most helpful answer as solving your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use a flatmap :-)

```
myArray.flatMap(item => item.domains.map(domain => ({ id: item.id, url: domain })));
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize there was a flatMap() method. Much appreciated!

Comment: Its new but surprisingly useful for accumilating :-)